# Plotting in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, plotting, dataframe

I have been searching for methods to plot in PySpark.

I couldn't find any resource on plotting data residing in DataFrame in PySpark. The only methods which are listed are:

- through method `collect()` which brings data into 'local' Python session and plot
- through method `toPandas()` which converts data to 'local' Pandas Dataframe.

The problem is that these both are very time-consuming functions. Is there any method by which we can plot data residing in Spark session directly (not importing it into the local session)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such method, I have found out.

The reason is, plotting libraries run on a single machine and expect a rather sample dataset. Data on Spark is distributed among its clusters and hence needs to be brought to a *local* session first, from where it can be plotted.

That is why methods such as `collect(), toPandas()` are needed.

Comment: Could you show where you found that information?